# How to filter price range from high to low and vice versa in django

Tags: django, filter

Basically I am developing an eCommerce site where there is list of products in product listing page. And i need to show the products according to price range from high to low and vice versa.

Comment: You need to be more explicit if you want people to help you. There are many examples of filters in django. Here is one https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your Product model is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...
```

Your queryset for High to low price range has to be:

```
products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-price')
```

and for Low to high price range:

```
products = Product.objects.all().order_by('price')
```